# Dependency Injection with options pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I'm trying to load some settings from the appsettings file and I've got a small issue with the way lists are loaded when using the options pattern. Suppose I've got the following classes (for loading the settings):

```
public class Application {
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
    public IEnumerable<string> Roles { get; set; } = new[] {""};
    public Application ToApplicationWithoutPass() => 
        new Application {
            Name = Name,
            Username = Username,
            Roles = Roles.ToList()
        };
}

public class Applications {
    public IEnumerable<Application> AppList { get; set; } = new List<Application>();
}
```

And here is what the settings that are defined on the *appsetings* file look like:

```
"Applications": {
  "AppList": [
    {
      "Name": "SraWebuserAdmin",          
      "Roles": [ "SraEntitiesWriters", "SraEntitiesReaders", "SraEntitiesLoginAccess" ]
    },
```

...

Here are the entries from the DI setup which is done on the `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.Configure<Applications>(options => Configuration.GetSection("Applications").Bind(options));
services.AddScoped<IApplicationAccessVerifier, ApplicationAccessVerifier>();
```

And, finally, here's the constructor of the ApplicationAccessVerifier class:

```
public ApplicationAccessVerifier(IOptionsSnapshot<Applications> applicationOptions) {
  _applicationOptions = applicationOptions;
}
```

Now, the question: if I don't initialize the `AppList` property,

```
public class Applications {
    public IEnumerable<Application> AppList { get; set; }
}
```

then the settings are loaded correctly.

However, if I initialized it like I've shown (making sure the filed wrapper by the property is initialized with an empty list), then the settings won't be copied to the `AppList`.

I find this strange since simple properties (ex.: `Name` on the `Application` class) aren't affected by the same issue.

Can anyone tell me why this happens or point me to an official documentation about it?

Comment: I have been able to reproduce the described issue. Arrays are treated differently and there are a combination of reasons for your based on the types used for the properties you are trying to bind.

Comment: do you have `applicationOptions.Value.AppList` items from the configuration file in the `ApplicationAccessVerifier` ? Probably you have not added the `.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")` to the `ConfigurationBuilder` chain?

Comment: @Nkosi I've just checked and found that both `IEnumerable<Application> AppList` and `IEnumerable<string> Roles` are properly deserialized with `Bind(options)`

Comment: @oleksa When a default value has been applied as shown in their example? I am able to recreate the exact problem described. I was then able to use a combination of different options to solve the issue depending on the type used and what default value was applied.

Comment: @Nkosi you are right, the ASP.net config system does not read the `AppList` property if it has default value set by the code. However both `System.Text.Json` and `Newtosoft.Json` deserialize the config object properly. I've created the [gist for this case](https://gist.github.com/oleksabor/6ae0627d6058efd33f815c9b10ef6c61)

Comment: Hello guys. Thanks for the feedback. Has anyone found anything about this on the docs?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues/759